# Architecture patterns applied in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, architecture

does anybody know which architecture patterns the eclipse team applied to their eclipse IDE? 

Thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Architecture

Comment: Big Ball of Mud comes to mind: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/09/big-ball-of-mud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Book [The Architecture of Open Source Applications](http://www.aosabook.org/en/index.html) contains a chapter about the design and architecture of eclipse. You can read the chapter online [here](http://www.aosabook.org/en/eclipse.html).